# Error in creating a calculated column that refers to a linked table in Power Pivot

Tags: relationship, dax, calculated-columns, powerpivot

**Context:**
I have a data model in Power Pivot with two tables, tTasks and tCaseworks. They are linked through the common field casework_id (unique to tCaseworks). I am attempting to create a calculated column in tCaseworks that checks whether or not that particular casework has any (i.e. one or more) corresponding tasks.

I have attempted the following DAX code:

```
has_task =
    IF (
        CONTAINS (
            RELATEDTABLE ( tTasks );
            tTasks[casework_id]; tCaseworks[casework_id]
        );
        "Yes";
        "No"
    )
```

**Problem:**

When I have typed in the formula and pressed enter and the code attempts to compile, I receive an error pop up stating (roughly translated):

Power Pivot for Excel:

An unexpected error (fil xmvsquery.cpp, line 13960, function XMVSXJoin::BuildRelationships). Process operation was terminated because the number of errors that were found reached the given limit for accepted errors in the operation. The current operation was annulled because another operation in the transaction failed.

The calculated column remains blank when I press OK on the pop-up. However, when I e.g. change the column name on another (new) calculated column, the column has_task suddenly calculates and provides the expected result.

**Questions:**
My questions are:

1. What kind of error is happening here and why?
2. Can this lead to other complications in the future or can I just proceed once I have the desired outcome?

Appreciate all the help.

[image]