# How to avoid circular dependency error in multiple calculated columns when deleting all data in data model?

Tags: dax, calculated-columns, powerpivot, circular-dependency

**Context:**

I have a data model in Power pivot with three tables, tTasks, tCaseworks and tCaseworkStatus. I am attempting to create two calculated columns in tCaseworks which from the two data tables. All three tables are linked through the common field casework_id (see illustration below).

The data model is regularly updated with new data. The way I am doing this is as follows:

- All three tables are sourced from three corresponding tables in my Excel workbook.
- A VBA script deletes all records in the three Excel tables and then refreshes the data model (sidenote: because the data model demands lookup tables to not be empty the VBA code adds one row per table before refreshing).
- New data is then added to the excel tables and the data model is refreshed.

This process works perfectly.
[image]

**Problem:**

The problem arises when I am adding calculated columns to tCaseworks and then attempting to update the data as described above. I have added two calculated columns; **has_task** and **status_now**. I am using the following DAX code:

**has_task:**

```
has_task =
    IF (
        CONTAINS (
            RELATEDTABLE ( tTasks );
            tTasks[casework_id]; tCaseworks[casework_id]
        );
        "Yes";
        "No"
    )
```

**status_now:**

```
status_now =
VAR TableX = RELATEDTABLE(tCaseworkStatus)
VAR ResultX = IF(
    CONTAINS(TableX;tCaseworkStatus[casework_status_code];"Completed");"Completed";
    IF(CONTAINS(TableX;tCaseworkStatus[casework_status_code];"Dismissed");"Dismissed";
        IF(CONTAINS(TableX;tCaseworkStatus[casework_status_code];"Begun");"Begun";
            IF(CONTAINS(TableX;tCaseworkStatus[casework_status_code];"Created");"Created";
                "Find no status"))))
RETURN
ResultX
```

Both of these calculated columns work as expected as long as I do not delete the data in the model (I do have one hickup with both columns as described in this [separated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080039/error-in-creating-a-calculated-column-that-refers-to-a-linked-table-in-power-piv), but I think that is unrelated).

When the data has been deleted and I refresh the model I get the following error message:

*"We cannot get the data from the data model. This is the error message we got: A circular dependency was discovered: 'tCaseworks'[status_now],'tCaseworks'[status_now],'tCaseworks'[has_task],'tCaseworks'[has_task],'tCaseworks'[status_now]."*

**Question:**

What is creating this dependency and how can I avoid it?

**My attempted solutions:**

The problem only arise when there are two of these calculated columns. Any one of these two works perfectly without the other upon refreshing. I know that calculated columns are prone to circular problems, but unfortunately I need to use columns and not measures. I suspect that perhaps my choice in formula is creating the problem, most likely the **contains-function**. However, I don't know about any alternative ways of building the formulas I need. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
I originally only posted a portion of my data model as I wanted the question to be as concise as possible but I guess it might have been confusing. The whole model concerns five objects from a case handling system: Claims, Cases, Caseworks, Tasks and Action Points. These objects are hierarchical, one claim can have one or more cases, but one case can only have one claim. Similarly, a case can have several caseworks, a casework can have several tasks, a task can have several action points. Additionally, the latter four can have a status attribute which is changed regularly.

I attempted to organize my data model in such a way that I had a lookup table for each object with unique values. I have many attributes for each object in my data that I did not include in the example above, and my goal was to add useful attributes through calculated columns in these tables. The data tables with the changes were intented to provide insight to the lookup tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship model is a bit unusual. DAX works best when using something like [dimensional fact model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_fact_model)
I would consider the `tCaseworkStatus` a fact table since its like a log of the changes to your data. `tTasks` is a dimension, since it just add an extra dimension to your data.
The `tCaseworks` is not necessary since it doesn't hold any actual data (only calculated data).

if you want your current model to work, it might fix your problem if you just delete the relationship between `tTasks` and `tCaseworks`, and add a new between `tTasks` and `tCaseworksStatus`

edit.
it just occurred to me that the reason you have it like this, is that you may have a many-to-many relationship between `tTasks` and `tCaseworksStatus`. if that is the case you might have to create a proper [many-to-many table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)). which is kind of what your `tCaseworks` is, but you cant have a relationship to the same key like you currently have.

edit2.
the solution seemed to be that somehow the `Relatedtable` function in conjunction with the relationship model was causing the error. using `Lookupvalue` instead seems to to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have added some more information about my data model in the question. Hopefully that makes the context more clear. If I understand your answer correctly, you seem to argue that it isn't possible for a primary key in one table to have more than one 1:many relationships to other tables? I am new to Power Pivot and DAX and this might be true, but I fail to see why that should be. Intuitively I would think that drastically reduces the usability of such tools?

Comment: well that makes a bit more sense now :-) it is not impossible to reference the same key in multiple tables. but it raises some question about what is the relationship between `tCaseworkStatus` and `tTasks`. can you have a `tCaseworkStatus` if there is no `tTasks`? and vice versa?.  
i'm not sure where the circular dependency occurs, but i guess it hase something to do with relatedtable function.

Comment: btw. have you checked that the circular reference is not generated somewhere else in the excelfile. how is the status_now generated or how is a task generated

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Good question, tCaseworkStatus and tTasks are independent of each other. So the easiest way to describe it is that these are two are independent events that can occur on the same object (casework), and thus are linked through the casework_id field. I have checked throughly and it is definitely these calculated columns that causes the circular dependency. What I don't get is that the problem only occurs after I have deleted the data in the tables/data model, not when I define the calculated columns. Until data deletion, the columns give me the expected results.

Comment: As for your hypothesis about the relatedtable function, your are probably correct. I managed to circumvent the problem by rewriting the formulas for has_task and status_now using lookupvalue functions rather than relatedtable/contains-formulas. That seemed to do the trick. Notably, the problem ceased to exist when I changed one of the two columns away from relatedtable. Thus, I can only deduce that somehow using two or more relatedtable dependencies on the same relationship probably interfer with row context transition or something. My takeaway is thus to redesign future formulas accordingly.

Comment: sounds good, I created your problem in excel. with the same dependencies and dax formulas, but i couldn't recreate the problem. That is why I was thinking that it might be that there is another way they were linked.

Comment: That is very interesting. Hmm. The model is fairly complex so it is possible. In which case, it would be very interesting to identify the real issue. I think I will attempt to recreate the problem myself in a fresh workbook and see if I get the same result. Thank you!